# Is this rss feed valid?

Tags: xml, rss, safari, validation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" >
  <channel>
    <title>tttttts</title>
    <description></description>
    <link>http://sssss.com</link>
    <item>
  <title>Test</title>
<link>http://ssss.com/</link>
</item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Domain is password protected. I can't use web services to check.
Is this valid rss? Safari is throwing this error:

> Safari can’t open the page “feed://ddd”. The error is: “unknown error” (CFURLErrorDomain:303) Please choose Help > Report Bugs to Apple, note the error number, and describe what you did before you saw this message.

But its rendering fine in IE and FF. Chrome is just dispaying the xml as content.

Comment: When in doubt: http://validator.w3.org/feed/#validate_by_input

Comment: hi added...domain is password protected hence i can't use web services to check.

Comment: that's why I linked to the direct input version. Copy, paste, ding! fries are done.

Comment: How is the server serving your feed? See what the browsers' developer tools say about the HTTP response for your feed.

Answer (score 1):

You could upload your feed to a live server and then check it here:

http://feed2.w3.org/check.cgi

**EDIT:** I checked it by creating a file and adding it to my server.  Here are the recommendations:

> This feed is valid, but
>   interoperability with the widest range
>   of feed readers could be improved by
>   implementing the following
>   recommendations.

```
line 10, column 0: item should contain a guid element [help]
  </item>

line 11, column 2: Missing atom:link with rel="self" [help]
  </channel>
```

**EDIT 2:** Chrome does not display xml feed data in a readable way (like FF and IE).  In order to make it readable, you will need to style the content with `xsl`.